# object dependancies in an ms-access database

Tags: ms-access

Is it a good idea to use object dependancies to clean out unused objects in an ms-access database?

I am going to answer this question myself because I just did this and now I need to fix this access database because things are now broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is not alone. It is important to realize that object dependancies do not extend to code or to in form functions like Dlookup.

In a simple database without to many bells and wistles, it is probably fine, but in a more complex database with lots of code, it is risky.

Comment: Ouch. Very risky indeed. Even the smartest automatism wouldn't catch things like `Set qd = DB.Querydefs("myQuery_" & strName)`